# C/CPP version of BeautifulSoup especially at handling malformed HTML

Tags: c++, html, c, html-parsing

Are there any recommendations for a c/cpp lib which can be used to easily (as much as that possible) parse / iterate / manipulate HTML streams/files assuming some might be malformed, i.e. tags not closed etc.

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[HTMLparser](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html) from [Libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) is easy to use (simple tutorial below) and works great even on malformed HTML.

**Edit** : Original blog post is no longer accessible, so I've copy pasted the content here.

> Parsing (X)HTML in C is often seen as a difficult task.
>   It's true that C isn't the easiest language to use to develop a parser.
>   Fortunately, libxml2's [HTMLParser](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html) module come to the rescue. So, as promised, here's a small tutorial explaining how to use libxml2's HTMLParser to parse (X)HTML.
>
> First, you need to create a parser context. You have many functions for doing that, depending on how you want to feed data to the parser. I'll use `htmlCreatePushParserCtxt()`, since it work with memory buffers.
>
> ```
> htmlParserCtxtPtr parser = htmlCreatePushParserCtxt(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
> ```
>
> Then, you can set many options on that parser context.
>
> ```
> htmlCtxtUseOptions(parser, HTML_PARSE_NOBLANKS | HTML_PARSE_NOERROR | HTML_PARSE_NOWARNING | HTML_PARSE_NONET);
> ```
>
> We are now ready to parse an (X)HTML document.
>
> ```
> // char * data : buffer containing part of the web page
> // int len : number of bytes in data
> // Last argument is 0 if the web page isn't complete, and 1 for the final call.
> htmlParseChunk(parser, data, len, 0);
> ```
>
> Once you've pushed it all your data, you can call that function again with a `NULL` buffer and `1` as the last argument. This will ensure that the parser have processed everything.
>
> Finally, how to get the data you parsed? That's easier than it seems. You simply have to walk the XML tree created.
>
> ```
> void walkTree(xmlNode * a_node)
> { 
>     xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;
>     xmlAttr *cur_attr = NULL;
>     for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next)
>     {
>         // do something with that node information, like... printing the tag's name and attributes
>         printf("Got tag : %s\n", cur_node->name)
>         for (cur_attr = cur_node->properties; cur_attr; cur_attr = cur_attr->next)
>         {
>             printf("  ->; with attribute : %s\n", cur_attr->name);
>         }
>         walkTree(cur_node->children);
>     }
> }
> walkTree(xmlDocGetRootElement(parser->myDoc));
> ```
>
> And that's it! Isn't that simple enough? From there, you can do any kind of stuff, like finding all referenced images (by looking at `img` tag) and fetching them, or anything you can think of doing.
>
> Also, you should know that you can walk the XML tree anytime, even if you haven't parsed the whole (X)HTML document yet.
>
> If you have to parse (X)HTML in C, you should use libxml2's `HTMLParser`. It will save you a lot of time.

Comment: link for tutorial is broken

Comment: @gidim Thanks for reporting, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

you could use Google [gumbo-parser](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser)

> Gumbo is an implementation of the HTML5 parsing algorithm implemented as a pure C99 library with no outside dependencies. It's designed to serve as a building block for other tools and libraries such as linters, validators, templating languages, and refactoring and analysis tools.

```
#include "gumbo.h"

int main() {
  GumboOutput* output = gumbo_parse("<h1>Hello, World!</h1>");
  // Do stuff with output->root
  gumbo_destroy_output(&kGumboDefaultOptions, output);
}
```

There's also a C++ binding for this library [gumbo-query](https://github.com/lazytiger/gumbo-query)

> A C++ library that provides jQuery-like selectors for Google's Gumbo-Parser.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Document.h"
#include "Node.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  std::string page("<h1><a>some link</a></h1>");
  CDocument doc;
  doc.parse(page.c_str());

  CSelection c = doc.find("h1 a");
  std::cout << c.nodeAt(0).text() << std::endl; // some link
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've only used [libCurl C++](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/cplusplus/) for this type of thing but found it to be pretty good and useable. Don't know how it would cope with broken HTML though.

Answer (score -4):

Try using SIP and run BeautifulSoup on it might help.

More details on below link thread. OpenFrameworks + Python